# Special characters in NetBeans license templates

Tags: netbeans-8

How do I get special characters in a custom NetBeans license template? I need an o-umlaut ('ö') in a name. If I just type the character into the template, it produces garbage when the template is applied. I've tried replacing it with Unicode \0x00F6, but that just comes out as is.